# Платный контент в приложении Android

Tags: android, google-play

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать платный контент в приложении под Android. 
Я разрабатываю игру, в которой будут дополнительные уровни, которые будут открыты если человек оплатит определенную сумму.

Как это реализовать с точки зрения программиста? Наверняка есть определенные API от Google, какие то сервисы и прочее. т.е. в целом какой механизм этой реализации?

Спасибо большое!

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы по монетизации приложений не относятся к программированию.

Comment: Да, только как это реализовать с точки зрения программиста? Наверняка есть определенные API от Google, какие то сервисы и прочее. т.е. в целом какой механизм этой реализации?

Comment: @Olter Здесь вопрос о реализации такой фишки как "микротранзакции", т.е. покупки в приложении. API для этого есть, называется [Google Play Billing API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html). На русском можно почитать [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/160911/).